# Stripe webhooks : Is there a way to fire the event : customer.source.expiring in test mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks

Is there a way to fire the event

> customer.source.expiring

in test mode ?

I added a card expiring in the current month to the customer. I'd like to catch the webhook without waiting until the end of the current month.

Thanks

Comment: You can send in the event JSON to your webhook endpoint manually if you'd like to test how you're handling it. Is that not sufficient enough?

Comment: @matov How to generate a JSON with data matching to my test env ?

Comment: In your [own test dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/events) you can see the event JSONs Stripe is sending you to your webhook endpoint. You can filter them for a past expiring event if you have. Then all you'd need to change potentially is the customer id in the JSON. If you don't have that handy, you can pick one of the `customer.source.updated` events and change the event type to `customer.source.expiring`

Comment: Nice idea, but I will be stopped by the tool I use [StripeEvent](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event#testing) which checks the id event. So I will be able to change the customer id, but not the event id because it does not exist in my env.

Comment: There is sadly no way for now to trigger it outside of being at the start of the month and having a test card expiring at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it from Stripe Console after Login. Go to webhook section and from there you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of Jan 2022, there still seem to be no way of triggering this event using the Stripe CLI.
Anyhow, by digging a bit, I discovered a gist with the event's payload, that at least could help you set the code in order to receive the data

https://gist.github.com/mladenilic/a1b8ca4593d3d6f7db0d2159661d4e99

Obviously the testing part will still be a pain the butt.
Hope this could help.